# how to build custom project structure for custom platform

Tags: javascript, java, build

i have a custom web application platform.so we have a very specific folder structure and some files inside it.
basiccaly when we create a new project what we do is

create a folder - app

create folder structure - actual structure is more complex for to keep things simple i only added few folders.

```
app --|-- config.json
      |
      |-- js
      |
      |-- css
      |
      |-- images
      |
      |-- helper
      |
      |-- common
```

then we have to add project name to `config.json`

finally we have to copy files into those directories and replace project name with new project name.

i used to do that manually and it takes lot of time and very repetitive work.so i decided to create a simple application which will ask project name and then will do the rest automatically.

```
__________________________________________
|                                      X  |
|-----------------------------------------|
|                                         |
|  xplatform create project.              |
|                                         |
|  Enter project name : test              |
|                                         |
|  Project created successfully !         |
|                                         |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

my idea was to create a simple app in java.but then i heard about build tools
so i take a look at `gradle` , `grunt`,'gulp'.

but i'm confused .i need to know it it really possible to do with build tools.or do i have to build a new application from scratch?

thanks you

Comment: Yes it is possible to do this kind of thing with a build tool.  However, there is not sufficient information to determine if you can just do it "by configuration" or whether you need to write a custom plugin for the build tool to do it.

Comment: @StephenC thanks you for the response.can you tell me what kind of information required to determine that.

Comment: Basically ... what your manual procedure is for copying files, and what format of archive you are assembling them as.  (JAR? WAR? ZIP? ...)  Also, it is not clear if this procedure happens at the start of your project development, or if it happens at the end; i.e. in preparation for deployment.